# Which decision tree algorithm does scikit-learn use by default?

Tags: scikit-learn, decision-tree

There are a couple of algorithms to build decision trees such as CART (Classification and Regression Trees), ID3 (Iterative Dichotomiser 3) etc

Which decision tree algorithm does scikit-learn use by default?

When I look at some decision-tree python scripts, it magically produces the results with `fit` and `predict` functions.

Does scikit-learn cleverly choose the best decision-tree algo based on the data?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It doesn't automatically do so.

If we look at the [sklearn.tree.DecisionTreeClassifier](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.tree.DecisionTreeClassifier.html#sklearn.tree.DecisionTreeClassifier) page, we can see that the default criteria is gini impurity.

There is also an option to use entropy instead for the criterion.

Note that CART uses gini impurity and ID3 uses entropy as splitting criteria.

Answer (score 2):

They actually use CART but the splitting criterion is both gini and entropy. You can look into [How to tune a Decision Tree?](https://towardsdatascience.com/how-to-tune-a-decision-tree-f03721801680) for explanations of what happens under the hood.

Answer (score 1):

From official documentation, It uses [CART](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/tree.html#tree-algorithms-id3-c4-5-c5-0-and-cart:%7E:text=scikit%2Dlearn%20uses%20an%20optimized%20version%20of%20the%20CART%20algorithm%3B%20however%2C%20scikit%2Dlearn%20implementation%20does%20not%20support%20categorical%20variables%20for%20now.).

Comment: I add to your answer the following quote from the docs : "scikit-learn uses an optimized version of the CART algorithm; however, the scikit-learn implementation does not support categorical variables for now."